# Error convert pojo to json(cxf JAX-RS : Data Bindings)

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, cxfrs

i have next pojo:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "domain")    
@Entity
    class Domain {
      @ManyToOne 
      private Domain parent;
    
      @OneToMany //add column definitions as needed
      private List<Domain> subdomains;
    }
```

and rs service:

```
@GET
@Path("/domains/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Bus getDomains(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid){
    return domainsService.getByUuid(uuid);
}
```

when I try to access a resource, I get a loop and

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.StartTag.addNamespaceDecl(StartTag.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.StartTag.getPrefix(StartTag.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.DatatypeWriter$1$5.print(DatatypeWriter.java:114)
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.DatatypeWriter$1$5.print(DatatypeWriter.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.Document.writeValue(Document.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.StartTag.addAttribute(StartTag.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.ContainerElement._attribute(ContainerElement.java:318)
    at com.sun.xml.txw2.ContainerElement._attribute(ContainerElement.java:313)
```

how to properly transform classes that contain references to themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting into an infinite loop, because when your subdomain tries to render its parent the parent then renders all its subdomains where each subdomain will try to render parent again and so on and so forth until you run out of memory. So, to solve your problem add annotation `@JsonIgnore` over your `parent` property in your `Domain` class

Comment: thx, Michael, i got correct json, but i still get the same error wnen want to get wadl cxf

Comment: I think it has something to do with the construction of the <grammars /> block

Comment: Don't know about wadl, haven't used it in a long time. But probably, it is similar reason there - so look for annotation to ignore the field there