# Foreign key returns null when add as JSON content in ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two models and when i try to add a new file the file_id is null. How can I fix that?

Customer :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String CustomerName;

    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<File> File = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

File :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
public class File implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String file_name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customer Customer;

  }
```

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface FileRepository extends JpaRepository <File,Integer> {

   
}
```

I think problem is in mapper class. I want to add integer.
Mapper :

```
public class FileMapper {

    public static FileDTO toDto(File file){
        File DTO fileDTO = new FileDTO();
        fileDTO.setFile_name(file.getFile_name());
        fileDTO.setCustomer(file.getCustomer());



        return fileDTO;

    }

    public static File toEntity(FileDTO fileDTO){
        File file = new File();
        file.setFile_name(fileDTO.getFile_name());
        file.setCustomer(fileDTO.getCustomer());


        return file;

    }
```

Controller :

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/addFile")
    public boolean addFile(@RequestBody FileDTO File) {
     return FileService.addFile(FileMapper.toEntity(file));
    }
```

I want to add File with JSON Content and use `customer_id` as foreign key. But `customer_id` returns null when I add file.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like yours more common error is `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. I am not sure why your property is not added. But in any case there is a problem in your code. in your child Entity, in your case in class `File` (I would suggest to change the class name, but this is not related to this issue) add annotation `@JsonIgnore` over your `private Customer Customer;` property. See my answer to this question for the explanation: [Error convert pojo to json(cxf JAX-RS : Data Bindings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388204/error-convert-pojo-to-jsoncxf-jax-rs-data-bindings/69388301#69388301)

Comment: Thanks Michael but still same.I'm new to Spring Boot. I added the mapper class for file object. I think problem can be there.

Comment: I don't think you need a mapper. I see you use lombok library. I really don't like it. Try may be without it and add your getters and setters manually. Also change the names of variables from to start from lower case letter like change "File" to "file" (java convention).